# NA if the value is enclosed between NA

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I'm trying to clean my data. Let's imagine that we've got a vector of 20 values with several `NAs`:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(20, mean = 10, sd = 5) %>% round
x[c(6, 8, 12, 16, 19)] <- NA
```

So it looks smth like this:
 `>  4 11 15 -2 12 NA  7 NA  7  6  8 NA  6 10 15 NA  7  5 NA 22`

I need to replace those values which are enclosed with `NA` with `NA`). E.g. `7` from my vector should be `NA` cause previous and next values are `NA`. I can do it with `ifelse` statement and some `dplyr` functions:

```
library(dplyr)

ifelse(is.na(lag(x))&is.na(lead(x)), NA, x)

> 4 11 15 -2 12 NA NA NA  7  6  8 NA  6 10 15 NA  7  5 NA NA
```

The question is how can I replace two values enclosed with `NA`. `7` and `5` for example? I was trying to duplicate the condition, i.e. make `lag(lag(x))` and `lead(lead(x))` but I get a mess.

```
ifelse(is.na(lag(x))&is.na(lead(x)) | is.na(lead(lead(x)))&is.na(lag(lag(x))), NA, x)
 >  4 11 15 -2 12 NA NA NA  7 NA  8 NA  6 NA 15 NA  7  5 NA NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group per NA and count the length of each group. If it has length 3, then that means that the group consist of `NA, value, value`. We simply replace those values with NA.

```
i1 <- cumsum(is.na(x))
x[ave(i1, i1, FUN = function(i)length(i)) == 3] <- NA
#[1]  4 11 15 -2 12 NA  7 NA  7  6  8 NA  6 10 15 NA NA NA NA 22
```